# Roblox OnClick clothers giver script

Tags: lua, roblox

```
 pnts = script.Pants
shirt = script.Shirt

function onClicked(playerWhoClicked)

end
function GiveClothes(character)
if not character:findFirstChild("Shirt") then 
shirt:Clone().Parent = character
else character:findFirstChild("Shirt"):Destroy()
shirt:Clone().Parent = character
end

if not character:findFirstChild("Pants") then 
pnts:Clone().Parent = character
else character:findFirstChild("Pants"):Destroy()
pnts:Clone().Parent = character
end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(p)
p.CharacterAdded:connect(function(char)
wait(1.12)
local plr = game.Players:findFirstChild(char.Name)
print(char.Name)

local groupid = 0 -- Id of your group

local plr =  game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)

if plr then

if plr:IsInGroup(groupid) then

if plr:GetRoleInGroup(groupId) >= 50 
then GiveClothes(char)
end
end 
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClicked)
```

This script is supposed to give you certain clothes if you click on the button(Script is under the button and yes there is also a ClickDetector),but it only gives you the clothes if you are a certain rank in a Group.

But currently it does not work. How to fix this?

Comment: Be sure to include lots of information. Simply saying "it doesn't work" is not going to make people want to help you because the fact is anything could not work. Make sure to look in the output for any errors and if there are any to add them to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid weird names like `pnts`, you will probably not die from adding the letter `a`

[The ClickDetector already give you the player](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ClickDetector/MouseClick)

And it is over all messy

Try this:

```
local Pants = script.Pants
local Shirt = script.Shirt

local GroupID = 42 -- Group id here

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    if not Player:IsInGroup(GroupID) then return end
    if Player:GetRoleInGroup(GroupID) < 50 then return end
    local Character = Player.Character
    if Character == nil then return end

    -- Get new shirt
    local CharacterShirt = Character:findFirstChild("Shirt")
    if CharacterShirt then CharacterShirt:Destroy() end
    Shirt:Clone().Parent = Character

    -- Get new pants
    local CharacterPants = Character:findFirstChild("Pants")
    if CharacterPants then CharacterPants:Destroy() end
    Pants:Clone().Parent = Character
end)
```

Also make sure to post [errors](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Lua_errors) when you ask for help